# CouchDB Date functions

Tags: datetime, nosql, couchdb

We are in the process of converting a rather large PHP/MySQL project to Angular/Node.js/CouchDB.  The main problem I am running into now is that our MySQL queries are rather complicated, using a lot of date functions (like DATE_DIFF, DATE_FORMAT, etc.) and I don't know how to convert them to this new architecture.

How do most devs handle those types of functions in CouchDB?  Do they just pull the raw data from the database and leave all of the calculations up to the controller/front-end?

Example query:

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(NOW(),table.datefrom) as how_long, DATE_FORMAT(table.datefrom,'%m/%d/%Y') as formatted_date FROM table ORDER BY datefrom
```

How would that query be handled with CouchDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datetimes are not a "native" type in CouchDB. However, you have several good options that you can choose between depending on the situation.

You can use a "timestamp" numeric value. (either in the native milliseconds, or converted to seconds if needed) You can get a timestamp for "now" with `(new Date()).valueOf()`.

You can also break up the parts of your datetimes into an array. (`[ year, month, day, hour, minute, second ]`) This will enable you to use grouping to "drill down" into increasingly specific time-frames as well as query based on individual parts of the date.

If you want date manipulation and formatting from a tested library, you can pull in a 3rd party module like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) as a [CommonJS module](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CommonJS_Modules) that you can use in your view/show/list/etc.

I can see one potential issue with your example query above. You are basically getting a "seconds since" via `DATE_DIFF(NOW(), ...)`. In a view function, you won't be able to use a "transient" value like `NOW()` since views need to remain *unaffected* by outside variables/conditions. However, this is solved by adding a [list function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later) that can take your view results and transform the output to have "relative" values like what you are trying to achieve, and can also receieve querystring arguments to further add dynamism to your view.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Exactly what I needed.